# Subversion revert to a previous revision without adding to the head

Tags: svn

I'm working on a project with multiple collaborators. One of the programmer, overwrote several files by copying a file and pasting over it. The files have been committed.

The problem is that the annotations of the file, changed from having different annotators to only that programmer.

I want to revert to before he/she modified the file, so that the annotations would return.

Merge does not work, since it adds on to the head, and the result would cause all the annotations to change from that programmer to me.

Is there a way to revert this?

Comment: Did the programmer commit?  If you check out the directory again, are the annotations from the others still missing in the new working copy?

Comment: Yes, the files have been committed, which is the problem.

Comment: The only way to do it without reverse merge is via _svnadmin dump/svnadmin load_ filtering the offending revision out. But this is close to impossible to do for most of active projects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can revert the committed files.  Hopefully, they are all committed in one commit because you can revert the commit, not specific files with a commit.

In eclipse, you can go to Team, Show History - select the commit that contains the changes you don't want and select the context menu - select "Revert Changes from Revision ???".

This will bring that revision back to your workspace then you can commit.

As for the annotations, we have it updated on the build server so its whomever commits it...so you'll be out of luck.  Unless, you log in as the specific user yourself and commit it.  ;-)   Or get the developer to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Branch latest GOOD revision, change nothing, merge branch back with option  `--accept 'theirs-full'` (theirs will be "from branch")

BTW: if your company rely on `blame` results for something, you are on **extremely** Bad Way (tm)